# Facing errors during the unit test for sample .NET micro-service (vb)

Tags: .net, vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a sample micro-service written in visual basic in .NET framework it basically prints the message hello on localhost, Now I am trying to do unit test for it using NUnit. I want the test to check my Program.vb file and in that compare the string mentioned there with "Hello" is they match the test should pass but I am facing an error. Below is my Program.vb file;`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Imports Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
Imports Microsoft.FeatureManagement

Namespace HelloService
Public Class Program
    Private Const HelloFeatureEnabled As Boolean = True

    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function CreateWebHostBuilder(args() As String) As IWebHostBuilder
        Return New WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel().ConfigureServices(Sub(services)
                                                                       
services.AddLogging()
                                                                       
services.AddFeatureManagement()
                                                                   End 
Sub).Configure(Sub(app)
                                                                                         
app.UseMiddleware(Of FeatureToggleMiddleware)(HelloFeatureEnabled)
                                                                                         
 app.Run(AddressOf HandleRequest)
                                                                                     
End Sub)
    End Function

    Public Shared Async Function HandleRequest(context As HttpContext) As Task
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        Await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello")
    End Function
 End Class

 Public Class FeatureToggleMiddleware
    Private ReadOnly _next As RequestDelegate
    Private ReadOnly _logger As ILogger(Of FeatureToggleMiddleware)
    Private ReadOnly _helloFeatureEnabled As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal nextItem As RequestDelegate, ByVal logger As ILogger(Of 
FeatureToggleMiddleware), ByVal helloFeatureEnabled As Boolean)
        _next = nextItem
        _logger = logger
        _helloFeatureEnabled = helloFeatureEnabled
    End Sub

        Public Async Function InvokeAsync(ByVal context As HttpContext) As Task
              If _helloFeatureEnabled Then
                _logger.LogInformation("HelloFeature is enabled")
                Await _next.Invoke(context)
            Else
                _logger.LogInformation("HelloFeature is disabled")
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound
            End If
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And below is mu UnitTest1.vb file;

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports HelloService ' Adjusted namespace
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

Namespace HelloService.Tests ' Adjusted namespace
<TestFixture>
 Public Class UnitTest1
<Test>
   Public Async Sub TestHandleRequest() 
   Dim context As New DefaultHttpContext()
   Dim expectedResponse As String = "Hello"
   Dim actualResponse As String = Await 
   HelloService.Program.HandleRequest(context)  
   Assert.That(expectedResponse, Is.EqualTo(actualResponse))
   End Sub
   End Class
End Namespace
```

I am facing this error;

```
" error BC30456: 'Program' is not a member of 'HelloService.Tests.HelloService'. 
     [/home/cl/Desktop/New Folder/sample- 
     services/HelloService.Tests/HelloService.Tests.vbproj] "
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: You may want to double-check that the project settings aren't still putting the tests into a `HelloService` namespace.

Comment: And how to do that, Actually its my first time using vb. I am rookie .

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio, right-click on the project, choose "Properties", go to the "Application" ply, and look for the "Root namespace" field.  That should be be "HelloService.Tests" based on usage, but if you only changed in code, it might still be "HelloService".

Comment: I have a root folder named sample-services in that I have two folders one HelloService that contains Program.vb file and other one named HelloService.Tests floder in which UnitTest.vb is stored, I tried doing right click but there is no option named properties for both directories.

Comment: I would have expected there to be separate projects in Visual Studio, one test project and one service project.  If that's not the case, then I'm not sure how it works.  If you're not using Visual Studio, then this doesn't apply.

Comment: From folder view, I don't see a way to manage this.  If you're building from a solution, I would recommend to open the solution instead of opening the folder.